# How to have multiple page orientations in a SSRS 2012 Report?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2012

I’m using report builder 3.0 in SSRS 2012 to generate some reports, in one of them the first page should be vertically oriented and the rest pages should be horizontally oriented, I’m dealing with this for a while using page break but I couldn't change the page orientation only for one page, There is someone who knows how to do this? (I can't use a horizontal page and write vertical text, it's important to show it correctly on screen and pdf).

Please Help.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe the orientation is set per report.  With this in mind, you could make use of subreports to accomplish this.  Make a subreport for that page in a landscape orientation and simply include that where you would want it to be in the master.

Comment: I tried this option but I can't find a way to do it, do you have an url with an example or something that can be used as a Guide? Thx a lot!